# How to change fontsize using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Uni assignment that says I should change the font size of the anchor tags using a for loop.

```js
var actiVe = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < actiVe.length; i++) {
  actiVe[i].style.fontSize = (parseInt(actiVe[i].style.fontSize) * 2 + 'px')
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <!-- 
       1. Weise mittels einer Schleife allen Listenelementen eine andere Schriftgröße zu. Recherchiere gegebenenfalls nach "JavaScript Style Object Properties".
      -->
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the computed font size value instead, element.style.fontSize will return an empty string in some cases, for example for externally set font sizes (e.g. via css)

```js
var actiVe = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < actiVe.length; i++) {
  let fontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(actiVe[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));
  actiVe[i].style.fontSize = fontSize * 2 + 'px'
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <!-- 
                        1. Weise mittels einer Schleife allen Listenelementen eine andere Schriftgröße zu. Recherchiere gegebenenfalls nach "JavaScript Style Object Properties".
                    -->
  <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```